# How do understand a function that immediately returns another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

[I am confused by the following code.](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/React-Redux-Firebase-App/blob/lesson-18/marioplan/src/store/actions/projectActions.js)

[Source](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/React-Redux-Firebase-App/blob/lesson-18/marioplan/src/store/actions/projectActions.js)

```
export const createProject = (project) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirestore}) => {
    // make async call to database
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    firestore.collection('projects').add({
      ...project,
      authorFirstName: 'Net',
      authorLastName: 'Ninja',
      authorId: 12345,
      createdAt: new Date()
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT_SUCCESS' });
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR' }, err);
    });
  }
};
```

My question is about this line.

```
return (dispatch, getState, {getFirestore}) => {...
```

What makes this work? Where do the arguments come from? What calls them? Aren't all these arguments already in scope? Why do we need `createProject` to return a second function? Is `createProject` returning a second function? Or is it immediately invoking an inline function? What triggers the `return` function to run?

I'm just generally very confused by this pattern. Can someone please break it down for me?

Comment: Presumably the caller of `createProject` is expecting a function returned and will call the returned function with the `dispatch, getState, {getFirestore}` arguments. `createProject` looks like a function factory (ish).

Comment: @VLAZ Isn't it only classified as currying if each function in turn only takes 1 argument itself? This doesn't strike me as currying, just a typical higher order function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate technically yes, but it's more formally tranforming `f(a, b, c)` into being evaluated into steps where each satisfies the parameter. Some implementations do only allow you to turn the steps into `f(a) -> g(b) -> h(c)` while others make it also possible to go with `f(a) -> g(b, c)`. Besides, I can't really find a better duplicate than the concept of currying. Surely once one has that down, the arity of the functions is irrelevant to the result.

Comment: Are you using redux here?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Yes. Does that affect the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the simplest pattern:

```js
function outter(outterArg) {
  return function(innerArg) {
     console.log(outterArg, innerArg  )
  }
}
let retFunction = outter('outterValue')
// retFunction is that function returned from outter
// now call the retFunction
retFunction('innerValue')

// or call them on one line
outter('oneLineOutter')('oneLineInner')
```

Comment: I'm personally hesitant to mark this as a duplicate of the currying post, but if you're just going to post a simple example of currying, it would have been better to just vote on VLAZ's dupe post which contains far more information.

Comment: close and redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying ? All this lad needed was that this method is called "currying", now he can do some proper googling!

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Technically it is a duplicate, but this one is so quick and simple, some folks might like it.

Answer (score 1):

> Where do the arguments come from?

Just like any other function, arguments are passed in when you call the function.

> What calls them?

The returned function is called elsewhere. In this case, redux or react will call your `createProject()` function and get its return value. Then it will call the returned function with the appropriate parameters.

> Why do we need createProject to return a second function?

Redux is full of this pattern where you have a function which returns another function.

> Is createProject returning a second function?

Yes it is.

> Or is it immediately invoking an inline function?

No it is invoked later.

> What triggers the return function to run?

Redux eventually calls the returned function to run it.

Comment: +1 but where, [in the source code linked here](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/React-Redux-Firebase-App/blob/lesson-18/marioplan/src/store/actions/projectActions.js) does Redux call the inner function to run it?

Comment: @Mowzer The inner function is not called anywhere in that code which you linked because it isn't the source code for redux. Rather it is a library which uses redux to connect to firebase.